# ASP.NET , MySQL and sql query from

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql, select

Using ASP.net. I can connect to MySQL database fine. However, it seems that I cannot use the auto configure select statement since it's adding [] in the statement.

```
SELECT [main_id], 
       [main_user],  
       [main_regional], 
       [main_desc],
       [main_status],
       [main_ts] 
FROM [main]
```

How can I fix this? I can always use the custom sql statement but I really would like to use GUI; it is so easy and much faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this.
http://forums.asp.net/t/1747752.aspx/1